# Getting valgrind to show common errors

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

I ran valgrind with --track-origins=yes and so i assumed that it would show errors concerning uninitialized variables like this: 
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./pointer
also is it possible to permanently edit the settings of valgrind in a file of sorts ?

The code i ran it on was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   int age = 10;
   int height;
   printf("I am %d years old.\n");
   printf("I am %d inches tall.\n");

return 0;

}
```

This is my result from valgrind

```
==12005== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12005== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12005== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12005== Command: ./pointer
==12005== 
I am -16776936 years old.
I am 2147483633 inches tall.
==12005== 
==12005== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12005==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12005==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==12005== 
==12005== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12005== 
==12005== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12005== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

I was expecting something like this(from the 'Learn c the hard way')

```
==3082== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3082== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3082== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3082== Command: ./ex4
==3082== 
I am -16775432 years old.
==3082== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==3082==    at 0x4E730EB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==3082==    by 0x4E743D8: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1613)
==3082==    by 0x4E7E6F9: printf (printf.c:35)
==3082==    by 0x40052B: main (ex4.c:11)
==3082== 
==3082== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3082==    at 0x4E730F5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==3082==    by 0x4E743D8: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1613)
==3082==    by 0x4E7E6F9: printf (printf.c:35)
==3082==    by 0x40052B: main (ex4.c:11)
==3082== 
==3082== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3082==    at 0x4E7633B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1613)
==3082==    by 0x4E7E6F9: printf (printf.c:35)
==3082==    by 0x40052B: main (ex4.c:11)
==3082== 
==3082== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3082==    at 0x4E744C6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1613)
==3082==    by 0x4E7E6F9: printf (printf.c:35)
==3082==    by 0x40052B: main (ex4.c:11)
==3082== 
I am 0 inches tall.
==3082== 
==3082== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3082==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3082==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==3082== 
==3082== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3082== 
==3082== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3082== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3082== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I don't think it is *guaranteed* that Valgrind will detect such things. If varargs that are fetched but not passed come from the stack, then that part of the stack may have been initialized just "by accident".

However, in this particular case, you're probably seeing the effects of the AMD64 ABI, whereas the example you quote seems to be x86 (judging from the addresses not being larger than 32 bits). Since the AMD64 ABI passes up to six arguments in registers, `printf` won't even touch memory to fetch arguments until you give it more than that.

For instance, I tried this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%i %i %i %i %i %i %i\n");
    return(0);
}
```

With only six `%i` specifications, Valgrind warns of nothing, while with seven, I get warnings. I'm fairly sure that's because of arguments being passed in registers.

(I will admit, however, that I would have thought that 6 `%i` specifications should have been enough, however, seeing as how the format string itself consumes one register. I can't quite explain that effect. Unless, as I mentioned above, the first non-register argument just happened to have been initialized in memory.)

Comment: I tried it out and it seems to work the same way for me, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I could not help but notice that your printf calls do not actually use the variables. Did you notice that?

Which could be the reason it isn't working.

Comment: i changed this line:                                                                     printf("I am %d inches tall.\n"); -> printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);       is that what you meant?

Comment: Also I think Dolda2000 is on to something it definitely worked when I tried to print 7 variables with printf as he did